# Android Program unable to restart correctly

Tags: android

I have this program

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);        
       record();
       play();          
    }
}
```

When I executed it it would

1)Record my voice

2)Playback my voice

3)display "Hello World, MyActiviy" from the default XML file.

When I hit Home button and then relaunch the program it would go straight to #3 display the words without recording and playback my voice

Only if I go to Settings to force Stop the program in the background  then the program would run correctly.

My Question how to terminate the program correctly so it would execute #1 to #3 sequence correctly?

Comment: Use like this way. <activity android:name=".Terms" android:label="@string/app_name" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter>
 </activity>

Answer (score 0):

This is because the activity is not destroyed when it goes in background and consequently the `onCreate()` method is not called when the activity has focus again.

You have to move your code in `onResume()` method if you want to be executed each time the activity comes into foreground.

For more information see the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) diagram.